# Setting a tiled background to the page edge in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am hoping to release a short ebook that I have written in Libreoffice. I have created an image that is the same width as an A4 page. Under `Format > Page > Background` and changing from "as colour" to "as image" it is possible to set the image to tile. However the image justifies to the left hand margin of the text and not the page.

How can I get the background tiled image to cover the page?

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I get the background tiled image to cover the page?

1. "Format" > "Page" > Set all 4 page margins to "0", click "OK", then click "Yes"

   - Note: Not all printers can print to the edges of the page.

   [image]

   [image]
2. "Format" > "Page" > Select "Area" tab
3. Set "Fill" to "Bitmap"
4. Set "Postion" as appropriate for the image you wish to tile.
5. Click "Import Graphic" and choose your image, then click "OK"

   [image]

   Here you can see the image covering the whole page:

   [image]
6. To include text (such as a chapter title) on this page:

   - Create paragraph styles with appropriate margins, or
   - Place the text in a frame and position the frame where you want the text to appear.